# Tensorflow Slow after "Done running local_init_op"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have a tensorflow based code taken from github, which is very slow. It is even not printing (even after enabling DEBUG mode for tf.logging) what is happening after following is printed

INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.  *--> After this line code takes 20 minutes to execute*
INFO:tensorflow:prediction_loop marked as finished

Can someone please tell where to look at and optimize?
Following things are already checked:

- model_fn : this gets executed before local_init_op
- local files: checkpoint files are saved and loaded from local filesystem. So file transfer delay should not be the cause
- warm_start_from: tried. Had no effect on prediction time

Estimator code:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
      use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
      model_fn=model_fn,
      config=run_config,
      warm_start_from = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(
            ckpt_to_initialize_from='/content/ckpt',
        ),
      train_batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size,
      predict_batch_size=FLAGS.predict_batch_size)
```

Prediction Code:

```
results = estimator.predict(
          predict_input_fn, yield_single_examples=True, checkpoint_path='/content/ckpt/model.ckpt-10949')
```

Time taken when this code is executed:

```
results = list(results)
```

Comment: I think the model function is already executed, as per log printed below  

INFO:tensorflow:  name = cls/squad/output_bias:0, shape = (2,), *INIT_FROM_CKPT*  
----BEFORE TPUEstimatorSpec-----  
----AFTER TPUEstimatorSpec-----  
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.  
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.  
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /content/ckpt/model.ckpt-10949  
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.  
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.